# Перемещение элементов в Grid и Store ввех и вниз (изменение порядка) в ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте! Самостоятельно изучаю *ExtJS*...

Возник вопрос такого плана:
Есть **Grid** отображающий данные **Store** (получаются с сервера). Данные получаются стандартными порциями (применяется **Paging**, но собираюсь перейти на **PagingScroller**).
Так вот, одним из атрибутов элементов является ***pos*** (он в таблице не отображается, но **Store** его получает) по которому данные сортируются (на сервере, так как получаются они все таки постранично). Хочу сделать две кнопки на панели инструментов над таблицей (там уже имеются - добавление, правка, удаление): вверх и вниз. Которые будут менять этот атрибут - обменивать его с *верхним* или *нижним* элементом. В идеале конечно же хотелось бы иметь возможность мышью перетаскивать элементы в таблице на нужные позиции и вызывать соответствующее изменение атрибута ***pos***...

Но я пока не представляю как это можно сделать...
Надуюсь, что кто-нибудь мне с этим поможет...

Варианты типа

```
grid.getStore().remove(record, true);
grid.getStore().insert(index, record);
```

Прошу не предлагать - в данный момент их рассматриваю и они мне не нравятся - лишние действия, данные, - а ведь нужно изменить одноименный атрибут всего у двух записей...

*PS* Если необходимо и они влезут в вопрос, то могу привести фрагменты кода.